# Why is there a gap between border's border and border's background in wpf?

Tags: wpf

The following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="Red">
            <Border BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

produces the following output (.NET 4.6.1, Windows 10):

[image]

The red line should not be there. It seems to be a gap between the second border's border and the second border's background. I tried to set `SnapsToDevicePixels` to `True` but it doesn't change.

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the answers, `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` seems to solved the issue. But in fact I think it better highlight a bug in WPF. Because now, the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="Red">
            <Border Margin="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Grid Background="Black"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

produces the following output:
[image]

Comment: I copied your code in a WPF project and I didn't get that red line, you might have something else altering your visuals. I suppose you didn't include all the code to simplify the question.

Comment: I copied into a brand new project in VS2015 and it shows up there. Edit: design mode only, when I run it there's no red.

Comment: You're using W10, I suppose @AdamSills too, I'm using W7, so it's related on how the OS handles the visuals, I'm an ignorant on that field

Comment: @Tuco Win8 on my work machine was my first test (designer it shows up, running it does not). I just ran on my home machine which is Win10 and it exhibits the same behavior. There's got to be something else going on; I understand why you might see it in the designer, but my Win10 machine (RDP, but with full experience selected) I don't see it.

Comment: Try setting a default theme [Difference in WPF user interfaces between Windows 7 and Windows 8](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8eee18a1-c006-4242-990f-939cfde79b02/difference-in-wpf-user-interfaces-between-windows-7-and-windows-8?forum=wpf)

Comment: Try playing with SnapToDevicePixels and UseLayoutRounding. Layout in WPF is all floating point. It's arbitrary units, not pixels, so you can get rounding and weirdness. The intent is for it to be arbitrarily scalable, but since it's always being quantized to pixels for display (with anti-aliasing and other horrors) you get dogfood in many cases with these big clunky screen pixels.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the designer uses a fast algorithm to render the view and when running the executable a high quality one is used.

Setting RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" seems to force the designer to draw in high quality.

```
<Window.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
</Window.RenderTransform>
<Grid RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
    <Border Background="Red">
        <Border BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

To answer the second part of your question:

It is because your window is not snapped to the screen only the content is sapped to device pixels. It would work if the position of the window was snapped to the screen. Scroll/move it left and right and you will see that it sometimes snaps properly. I think it's a design problem where snapping is done in a post processing cycle after the MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride cycles are completed instead of snapping in between the parent and child calls. If it should snap the container border and send the proper available space to the grid in the measure override. WPF would then support snapping of parts of the layout properly.